# Chrome browser is not getting opening due to version issues even though driver updated with Webdriver-manager

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I tried to execute the test case with protractor using chrome browser but due to chrome browser update it is not getting compatible with version of chrome. i tried to update the chrome version by my findings in google and driver have been  updated in protractor folder but still facing same issue.

command used for updating the chrome driver version

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.70

chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_78.0.3904.70.zip
```

**Error Log**

```
W/launcher - Ignoring uncaught error SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver on
ly supports Chrome version 76
  (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.12 (220b19a666554bdcac56dff9ffd44c300842c933-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#83}),platform=W
indows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
```

When i start the selenium server i'm able to find the 76 version of chrome but in my webdriver-manager i'm able to find the latest version only

**Selenium serverlog chrome version details**

```
 -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pr
otractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_76.0.3809.12.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 types of installation:

- Global
- Local
- Local of your dependency (either global or local). I actually don't know if there is a definition to those installations

You are updating global, what you need to update is the local installation of your protractor

So try to navigate to your the protractor folder (I use local for tests), then run

`node ./bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome $VERSION`

Comment: Actually I updated both the local and global locations... Still I faced the same issue... And Sure I will try this and update here

Comment: it's working but with the above command it's not working.. i tried with the below command

```node ./bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.70```

Comment: obviously. `$VERSION` was just a placeholder for whatever version you're trying to install and needed to be substituted

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when running my e2e tests using Selenium and Protractor

```
error SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
```

I run the command mentioned in the last comment

```
 node ./bin/webdriver-manager update --gecko=false --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.87
```

inside my protractor folder

```
#PROJECT_NAME/node_modules/protractor
```

and worked like a charm

Thanks!